# AngularJS - Change ngClick function in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I have a scenario where in some cases I need to change the ngClick function on the fly, depending on user permissions. I would like to do this in a directive, and not the controller so it can be something that can be removed without serious consequences. Right now I can change the ngClick value in a directive with this:

```
attr.$set('ngClick', 'vm.testing()');
$timeout(function() {           
    scope.$apply();
});
```

This block of code changes the ngClick in the dom element to "vm.testing()" just fine. However, the event listener is still firing off the old function and not the newly added function. How would you about updating the listener to the new function?

Comment: This sounds like something that should be handled by the method referenced in ng-click, no? Or you can always just set vm.testing to point to something else. What specifically do you want to change the method to? An entirely different logic or just a generic "You lack permissions" message? And why change it on the fly? Do user permissions change on the fly?

Comment: Explain your reasoning for "I would like to do this in a directive, and not the controller"... This kind of situation *is* dealt with in the controller. The controller is the place (with the help of services) where you "reason" about the behavior of your app/view. Directives are meant to augment or assign behavior to a small part of the the View to which they apply

Comment: The reason I want to keep it in the directive is so we can remove or add it to any DOM without having to take apart a controller and figure out how to add restrictions, potentially breaking something. I decided to hi-jack the event click and stop it with this code:

    elem.on('click', function(event) {            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    });

Comment: @Speedy059 I don't agree with you. This is bussiness logic and should go in a controller. Directives should be as dumb as possible. Also, have defined an isolate scope in your directive?